# I don't understand this ruby code that converts from base-256 to decimal

Tags: ruby

[Code in Github](https://gist.github.com/jasiek/2781381)

The objective of the code is simple: convert base-256 byte string to base-10

```
def debase256(string)
  string.reverse.bytes.inject([0, 1]) do |(sum, pow), byte|
    [pow * byte.ord, pow * 256]
  end.first
end
```

I tried to read it, but I only went as far as 'reverse.bytes'

I can't imagine in my head how the bytes move and change during the process.

An example explaining this is all I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is wrong. It's not doing the sum. The first array item in the block should be `sum + pow * byte.ord`. Also, there's no point in having `byte.ord` as `Integer#ord` just returns itself.

Thus, the correct code would be:

```rb
def debase256(string)
  string.reverse.bytes.inject([0, 1]) do |(sum, pow), byte|
    [sum + pow * byte, pow * 256]
  end.first
end
```

---

This code is a bit hard to follow though. Maybe the following code (without the method declaration) helps you in understanding it better:

```rb
string.reverse.bytes.map.with_index do |byte, i|
  byte * 256**i
end.sum
```

Let's look at an example with the string `"Test"`:

```rb
string = "Test"
```

First, we reverse it:

```rb
string.reverse # => "tseT"
```

Then we get the bytes:

```rb
string.reverse.bytes # => [116, 115, 101, 84]
```

Now we want to construct a base 10 number from this base 256 number. We do this by multiplying each slot index `i` with `256^i` where `i` starts at 0.

```rb
"Test".reverse.bytes.map.with_index { |byte, i| byte * 256**i }
# => [116 * 256^0, 115 * 256^1, 101 * 256^2, 84 * 256^3]
# => [116 * 1, 115 * 256, 101 * 65536, 84 * 16777216]
# => [116, 29440, 6619136, 1409286144]
```

Finally, we take the sum, which is the base 10 representation of it.

```rb
"Test".reverse.bytes.map.with_index { |byte, i| byte * 256**i }.sum
# => 1415934836
```

---

In order to understand what we are doing, let's try the same thing with a base 10 to base 10 conversion. Let's assume we have a number in base 10, e.g. `1234`. We get the digits of this:

```rb
1234.digits
# => [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Notice how `#digits` already returns the digits reversed.

Now, in base 10, every slot `i` needs to be multiplied by `10^i` (compared to `256^i` above in the base 256 case):

```rb
1234.digits.map.with_index { |byte, i| byte * 10**i }
# => [4 * 10^0, 3 * 10^1, 2 * 10^2, 1 * 10^3]
# => [4 * 1, 3 * 10, 2 * 100, 1 * 1000]
# => [4, 30, 200, 1000]
```

Summing it will give us the base 10 number:

```rb
1234.digits.map.with_index { |byte, i| byte * 10**i }.sum
# => 1234
```

Thus, the only difference is the base, the logic is the same.

---

A further example that you might have encountered is an RGB color value in hex, e.g. `#ac4fbe`. For red, green, and blue we have a value ranging from 0 to 255 encoded in hexadecimal. Hexadecimal is a fancy word for base 16. Typically, hexadecimal digits are represented as `0` to `9` and `a` to `f`:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  a  b  c  d  e  f
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Knowing this, let's look at the red value of the color `#ac4fbe`, which is represented by the first to characters `ac`.

The logic here is the same as above. Reversing this gives us `ca`. If we get the base 10 numbers for each character, that's `[12, 10]`. Let's multiply each slot with `16^i`:

```
[12 * 16^0, 10 * 16^1] == [12 * 1, 10 * 16] == [12, 160]
```

The sum `12 + 160` is `172`, which is the value for the red component in the color.

Again, it's the same logic as in the other examples.

---

I hope these examples help you understand how this works. As an exercise, try converting this binary (i.e. base 2) number to base 10:

```
101010
```

Remember, these are the slots:

```
digits: 1 0 1 0 1 0
slot i: 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

(Hint: it's the answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything.)

Comment: Thank you very much! There was indeed a mistake, good thing you noticed. The answer is 42 hehe.

Answer (score 0):

`inject` performs a loop, where the "accumulating variable" (also known as "memo object") is a two-element array, which is initially set to `[0,1]`. On each iteration, this object is passed as `[sum, pow]` to the loop body, together with the next element from the input array, which is stored in `byte`. The loop body calculates the updated memo object to be used on the next iteration. The result of the `inject` is the final value of the memo object.

You can follow what is going on, by replacing the loop body by

```
[pow * byte.ord, pow * 256].tap do
  |new_sum, new_pow|
  puts "Working on byte #{byte.inspect}"
  puts "old sum and pow : #{sum},#{pow}" 
  puts "new sum and pow : #{new_sum}, #{new_pow}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this way of debugging the code will be very useful for me to do more analysis for the rest of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the string is "AB" (for which the ASCII codes are 65 and 66):

`string.reverse.bytes` gives you `[66,65]`

`[66,65].inject([0,1])` goes through the array `[66,65]` and brings along the result array `[0,1]` into every iteration. Your loop needs to return the altered version of the array and it gets passed to the next iteration.

Example 1:

```
[66,65].inject([0,1]) do |(sum, pow), byte|
  puts "sum: #{sum} pow: #{pow} byte: #{byte}"
  [sum, pow] # this gets passed to the next round
 end
```

This outputs:

```
sum: 0 pow: 1 byte: 66
sum: 0 pow: 1 byte: 65
```

With a different kind of "memo" array:

```
memo = []
[66,65].inject(memo) do |memo, byte|
  memo << "byte is #{byte}"
  memo
 end
 puts memo.inspect
```

This outputs:

```
["byte is 66", "byte is 65"]
```

So, inject is like `each`, but the given "memo" object will be passed from each round to the next.

The method uses the memo to hold two values: the sum and the multiplier for the next byte.

Adding debug output to the original method:

```
def debase256(string)
  string.reverse.bytes.inject([0, 1]) do |(sum, pow), byte|
    puts "sum: #{sum} pow: #{pow} byte: #{byte}"
    [pow * byte.ord, pow * 256]
  end.first
end
```

Running this with `debase256("ABC")` outputs:

```
sum: 0 pow: 1 byte: 67
sum: 67 pow: 256 byte: 66
sum: 16896 pow: 65536 byte: 65
```

So, we see that the input for the first round's `|(sum, pow), byte|` is `(0, 1), 67`.

`pow * byte.ord` is `1 * 67 = 67`

`pow * 256` is `1 * 256 = 256`.

So, the `|(sum, pow), byte|` for the second round will be: `(67, 256), 66`.

`pow * byte.ord` is `256 * 66 = 16896`.

`pow * 256` is `256 * 256 = 65536`.

So the `|(sum, pow), byte|` for the last round is: `(16896, 65536), 65`:

`pow * byte.ord` is `65536 * 65 = 4259840`.

`pow * 256` is `65536 * 256 = 16777216`.

Because this was the last round, the block will return the memo, which is `[4259840, 16777216]`. The first element contains the desired result and the last one is no longer needed, so `.first` is called to just get the sum.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was very complete to understand the code. As well said @fphilipe the github guy was wrong but still your explanation is excellent.